# Best view architecture for drilldown UITableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, dropbox

Basically I want to recreate the "filebrowser" ("drilldown" Tableview) from the DropBox iPhone app using a UITableview and the DropBox SDK.

The SDK has a method `restClient` which, if called, returns the paths for all the files and folders at a given path. E.g.  `[self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/"];` or `[self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/Photos"];`

Currently the table gets populated by an array `filePaths` wich in its turn get's populated with paths by a call to the restClient method.

My initial idea was to create an array which helped me find out if a selected cell contained a path for a file or a folder - and in case of the latter would use `pushViewController` to load the same view but would populate `filePaths` by doing this `[self.restClient loadMetadata:pathInSelectedCell];`

I found out that this isn't the right way at all to tackle this problem (for numerous reasons), but I wouldn't know a way to do it differently.

What would be the right architecture for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

N.B. DropBox doesn't allow recursive directory/file listing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!

Turns out the best way for me was to pass the `filePath` to the newly created object thru a constructor.